# Reset value to default when using OnclickListener in Android

Tags: android, onclicklistener, countdowntimer

I'm trying to do some example about countdown timer using Button and set OnclickListener for that Button. My Default value is 10 and it will be decrease each second, how can i reset my value back to 10?

Comment: inside the OnClickListener stance write myCurrentValue = 10;

Answer (score 1):

`CountDownTimer` cannot be restarted, it can only be used once. You either have to create your own count down class that can handle being restarted, or just create a new instance of your `CountDownTimer` and cancel the old instance.

See the example code below where we have a `CountDownTimer` that counts down for 10 seconds in 1 second intervals, a `Button` that resets the timer when clicked (by cancelling the current timer and starting a new one), and a `TextView` that displays the time left in the current timer.

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {

    private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
    private TextView timerDisplayTextView;

    private static final long TEN_SECONDS = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(10);
    private static final long COUNTDOWN_INTERVAL = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(1);

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);

        Button myButton; // initialized here
        // timerDisplayTextView initialized here

        myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                countDownTimer.cancel();
                countDownTimer = getNewCountDownTimer(TEN_SECONDS);
                countDownTimer.start();
                showTimeInTextView(TEN_SECONDS);
            }
        });

        countDownTimer = getNewCountDownTimer(TEN_SECONDS);
        countDownTimer.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        countDownTimer.cancel();
    }

    private void showTimeInTextView(long millisecondsLeft) {
        timerDisplayTextView.setText(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisecondsLeft) + " seconds left");
    }

    private CountDownTimer getNewCountDownTimer(long length) {
        return new CountDownTimer(length, COUNTDOWN_INTERVAL) {
            @Override
            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                showTimeInTextView(millisUntilFinished);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFinish() {

            }
        };
    }
}
```